# Concatenate 2 dictionaries and Add parent to it

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have multiple dictionaries which i need to concatenate and add a parent in the end. How do i achieve this

```
dict1 = { "project":"test1", "summary": "A Test","issuetype": {
          "name": "Test"
       }}

dict2 = { "project":"test2", "summary": "B Test","issuetype": {
          "name": "Test"
       }}
```

I need it in format

```
dictParent = {fields: {
{ "project":"test1", "summary": "A Test","issuetype": {
          "name": "Test"
       }}
{ "project":"test2", "summary": "B Test","issuetype": {
          "name": "Test"
       }}
}}
}
```

I used below code

```
dictParent = {}
dictParent["fields"] = dict1, dict2
```

it kind of works the problem is it comes as as array but i want fields to be parent object not array

```
{fields: [
{ "project":"test1", "summary": "A Test","issuetype": {
          "name": "Test"
       }}
{ "project":"test2", "summary": "B Test","issuetype": {
          "name": "Test"
       }}
}}
]
```

Comment: You want your fields key to have some values. If you don't want them as a list what's the expected format for the value then? It can be any container like set, tuple or even an iterator, etc. Please specify what's the exact expected output and preferably why!

Comment: dictParent = {fields: {
{ "project":"test1", "summary": "A Test","issuetype": {
          "name": "Test"
       }}
{ "project":"test2", "summary": "B Test","issuetype": {
          "name": "Test"
       }}
}}
}


In the baove format filed contains a dict of values but no keys for it 

So the format is completly wrong

Answer (score 0):

This

> ```
> dictParent = {fields: {
> { "project":"test1", "summary": "A Test","issuetype": {
>           "name": "Test"
>        }}
> { "project":"test2", "summary": "B Test","issuetype": {
>           "name": "Test"
>        }}
> }}
> }
> ```

is invalid python:

- dictionary are `key:value` pairs -your second dictionary has *no key*
- your `fields` is not a string but a vairable specifier - my guess is you missed the `'fields'` around it

You can store your data like this (content shortened to stay below 80 char/line):

```
dictParent = {"fields": [ {"project":"t1", "summary":"A", "issuetype": {"name": "Test"}},
                          {"project":"t2", "summary":"B", "issuetype": {"name": "Test"}}] }
```

wich would make `dictParent` a dictionary with 1 key (`'fields'`) that has a list of dictionaries as value.

You can create it from dict1 and dict2 like so:

```
dictParent = { "fields": [dict1, dict2] }
```

Or you can specify different keys  (content shortened to stay below 80 char/line):

```
dictParent = {"fields_1": {"project":"t1", "summary":"A", "issuetype": {"name": "Test"}},
              "fields_2": {"project":"t2", "summary":"B", "issuetype": {"name": "Test"}}}
```

which would make `dictParent` a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
dictParent = { "fields_1":dict1, "fields_2":dict2] }
```

Comment: Thanks after digging more i figured out that i was i needed array not the format i originally posted. Thanks for the help